# Java local variable notation: 'textEntered' or 'enteredText'?

Tags: java, android, notation

I have just had a *not let me sleep* doubt about how to name a local variable which stores the text entered by an user (in a text box).

Should I name it 'enteredText' or 'textEntered'?

My main concern is about what comes first? participleSubject or subjectParticiple.

There are some accepted patterns as in events, where it is always onSubjectVerb, e.g. onItemClick ...

I am not sure which is the styling rule for my case (entering text in a TextBox'

I have made some searches on different code repositories and both names are used?

Any idea?

Thanks!

Miguel Ángel

Comment: Personal association: `enteredText` sounds like a `String` variable (`getEnteredText`), while `textEntered` could also be a boolean (`isTextEntered`). "entered text" sounds more like adjective + noun (thus describing a thing), while text entered sounds more like noun + verb (thus describing an action).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is one of the [two hardest problems](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html) in computer science, naming things. I think that both are equally non descriptive of **what** the text that has been entered describes.

For example: what does this text field provide the use the ability to enter? Their name? Then call it *userName*

Comment: If we are talking about coding a textbox here, the field could be actually the text entered by the user ;-)

Answer (score 1):

More of a matter of taste, I think.

Anyway for me it is a matter of context: if I'm writing a complex class or method with lots of variables and where e.g. there's text entered, text computed and text fixed (i.e. a label), I tend to name them `textEntered`, `textComputed` and `textFixed`, so when I need to access some kind of *text* the IDE auto completion features easily show me all `text`s available.

Comment: Complex class might be sign of bad design (the same applies for complex methods), more preferable is "Single responsibility principle".